# ipconfig in command it shows "ipconfig is not recognized as internal or external command""

Tags: flash, server

My Adobe Flash media server was successfully installed in my windows . but whenever i write ipconfig in command it shows "ipconfig is not recognized as internal or external command"

Answer (score 16):

Look in C:\Windows\System32 and see if you can find ipconfig there. If yes then you need to add the path:
Start -> search system -> advanced system settings -> advanced tab -> environment variables -> scroll down until you see path. Double click to add a path. at the end, put:

```
;C:\Windows\System32
```

or whatever your path is. keep clicking okay until you close out of everything... then try.

Comment: I had a similar issue with "ipconfig not recognized" after i inadvertently changed my Path directories when manually installing a Delphi IDE on Win7. I added the following three values in then restarted and it worked:
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

Answer (score 13):

It could indeed be down to system variables.

- Right click `My Computer` in Start Menu or on desktop and click `Properties`
- Choose `Advanced System settings` -> `Advanced` Click the `Environment Variables`
- button Find the system variable called `Path` and click it
- Click `Edit` button

It should be a long string with several paths separated by a semi-colons `;`. Check it contains `C:\Windows\system32` (I'm assuming your system drive is C). If you not sure if it is correct then you might want to copy it and post it here. If you make changes you may need to restart to see any effect. If this doesn't help then open your `C:\Windows\system32` directory and ensure it contains `IPConfig.exe`. If it doesn't then I guess you must be missing system files.

Answer (score 3):

If the ipconfig is not working, then it is due to path variable missing in your computer.

```
Please follow these steps to fix it.
1. Open the Start-Menu
2. Right click on ‘Computer’ and click ‘Properties’
3. Click ‘Advanced System Settings’ on the left hand side
4. Click ‘Environmental Variables’ at the bottom of the screen
5. Check for ‘Path’ in the list. If it is present,
a) Click ‘Edit’
b) Go to the end of the text box and type the following (without quotes): 

> `“;%systemroot%\system32”`

Otherwise, 
5. Click ‘new’  button,
a) In the next window, enter the variable name as “Path” (without quotes).
b) Enter the variable path as, “;%systemroot%\system32”  (without quotes).

6. Click ok and close the windows.
```

Now open a new command prompt and type ‘ipconfig‘, it should work fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can set PATH variable as above answers given

Else for fast process you can follow these steps

- open command prompt (by Window button + R then type "cmd" and press enter)
- make sure you are on the C:> drive
- go to System32 directory by:
  `C:\>cd Windows\System32`
- then type "ipconfig" and press enter your details will show

Answer (score 2):

If the ipconfig is not working, then it is due to path variable missing in your computer.

*Please follow these steps to fix it.*

1. Open the Start-Menu

- Right click on ‘Computer’ and click ‘Properties’
- Click ‘Advanced System Settings’ on the left hand side
- Click ‘Environmental Variables’ at the bottom of the screen
- Check for **‘Path’ **in the list. If it is present,
  a) Click ‘Edit’
  b) Go to the end of the text box and type the following `%systemroot%\system32`
  [edited from: `;%systemroot%\system32`]

> Otherwise

Click **new** button,

1. In the next window, enter the variable name as “Path” (without quotes).
2. Enter the variable path as, `%systemroot%\system32`
   [edited again]
3. Click ok and close the windows.
4. Open a new command prompt and type `ipconfig`

It should work fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Look in C:\Windows\System32 and see if you can find ipconfig there. If yes you just need to add the path by those steps

```
1- go to "my computer" right click  then click properties 

2- on your left-hand choose "Advanced System Settings" then Click
"Environmental Variables" at the bottom of the screen 

3- check on "Path" and click double click

4- click New then add this C:\Windows\System32  without semicolon I
mean this ; 

5-Ok, close cmd and run it again then try.
```